# Calling multidimensional array in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I've created a multidimensional array in javascript, but I need to convert to coffeescript. The multidimensional array works fine in javascript but doesn't seem to work properly when I convert using [JS2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) and I can't seem to find any solution online.

Here is my relevant code:

```
selectedCheck = [
  check_11_50
  check_11_250
  check_11_500
  check_11_1000
  check_11_2000
]
check_11_50 = [
  50
  69.99
  250
  169.99
  "1785-00050/check-11"
]
check_11_250 = [
  250
  169.99
  500
  230.99
  "1785-00250/check-11"
]
# ...
```

This should print "250".

```
console.log selectedCheck[1][0]
```

Comment: Side Note: You don't "call" arrays (or variables), you "use" them. You "call" *functions*.

Comment: Unrelated, but... I'd strongly recommend not using positions when you have object available to you. Using positions is brittle. Of course, if you're not in control of the data you're consuming, it doesn't matter.

Comment: That's not a multi-dimensional array, that's an array of arrays. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `check_11_50` and such **before** `selectedCheck`, as you're overwriting their values later:

```
check_11_50 = [
  50
  69.99
  250
  169.99
  "1785-00050/check-11"
]
check_11_250 = [
  250
  169.99
  500
  230.99
  "1785-00250/check-11"
]
# ...and so on...
selectedCheck = [
  check_11_50
  check_11_250
  check_11_500
  check_11_1000
  check_11_2000
]
```

Or of course, just do it all together:

```
selectedCheck = [
  [
    50
    69.99
    250
    169.99
    "1785-00050/check-11"
  ]
  [
    250
    169.99
    500
    230.99
    "1785-00250/check-11"
  ]
  # ...and so on...
]
```

Comment: Yep! When I did this I moved the defs around for clarity out of habit. *sigh*